# Changing Chrome extension site access has no effect

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extensions have a "Details" page (for example, here's [Adblock's](http://chrome://extensions/?id=gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)). On this page you can change the permissions of the extension to be one of: On click, On specific sites, or On all sites. These options determine whether the extension runs all the time on every site or only when you want them to.

[This extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reddit-check/mllceaiaedaingchlgolnfiibippgkmj), however, does not change behavior when I modify the permissions from its Details page. Why is this the case? Here's their source code on [Github](https://github.com/hsbakshi/reddit-check).

I noticed that they use a persistent background page. Would that cause the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That extension accesses only one site as you can see in its manifest.json so it won't run on anything else you're specifying. You can only narrow the permissions, not expand them. The background page type isn't relevant. The confusion stems from the fact that current permissions UI in Chrome is bad - it doesn't show the actual state, but it'll be fixed in Chrome 73, which is the current Chrome Canary.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I'm still a little confused because this extension does run on sites other than Reddit. Basically the way it works is it performs a Reddit search on whatever page you're currently viewing. The results are then displayed in the extension. My intended outcome from tweaking the permissions within Chrome is that the extension will only perform the Reddit search when I click it. Is the current Chrome permissions setting not able to provide this?

Comment: It doesn't actually run on sites other than Reddit. It just takes an URL of a tab and runs it through Reddit. Whereas the host permissions of an extension allow that extension access the contents of tabs/iframes with the corresponding URL, as well as make network requests to those URLs. You may want to read an overview/intro on how permissions work as I'm probably not good at explaining.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get what you mean. Do you want to post an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer as stated in the comments:

> [the extension] doesn't actually run on sites other than Reddit. It just takes an URL of a tab and runs it through Reddit.

This means that changing the permissions in the Details page doesn't affect anything.